# How do I tell how far an item is in a string in a list in C#

Tags: c#

Example:

```
    List<string> letters = new List<string>();

        letters.Add("A");
        letters.Add("B");
        letters.Add("C");
        letters.Add("D");
        letters.Add("E");
        letters.Add("F");
        letters.Add("G");
        letters.Add("H");
        letters.Add("I");
        letters.Add("J");
        letters.Add("K");
        letters.Add("L");
        letters.Add("M");
        letters.Add("N");
        letters.Add("O");
        letters.Add("P");
        letters.Add("Q");
        letters.Add("R");
        letters.Add("S");
        letters.Add("T");
        letters.Add("U");
        letters.Add("V");
        letters.Add("W");
        letters.Add("X");
        letters.Add("Y");
        letters.Add("Z");
```

If I had somebody input a letter in the list, how could I tell which number of the alphabet it is

Comment: `List<T>.IndexOf`?

Comment: `letters.IndexOf("A")` // returns 0;
`letters.IndexOf("A") + 1` // returns 1

Comment: there are way more efficient ways of finding what letter of the alphabet a character is

Comment: @pm100: But, his/her example is actually a perfect little [mcve]. I'm assuming the question is about the more general (though still pretty trivial) problem, not the extremely trivial problem his/her [mcve] presents

Comment: you can define your list with a one liner `var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray().Select((c) => c.ToString()).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

You can request the zero-based index of a listitem by using `List<T>.IndexOf(item)`.

However, for finding out what letter of the alphabet a character is I suggest converting the char to an integer and substracting the offset: `(Int32)[charToCheck]-96`, e.g. `(Int32)'a'-96` will return `1`

You could write an extension method for this purpose like so:

```
// startingIndex specifies if the first character of the alphabet should be 0 or any other number
public static Int32 GetPositionInAlphabet(this char character, Int32 startingIndex = 0)
{
    return (Int32)Char.ToLower(character) - 97 + startingIndex; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `letters.IndexOf(theletter) + 1`

`IndexOf` returns the 0-based index, that is, 0 for the first item, 1 for the second item, etc. This is why the **+ 1** is needed.